# Using regular expressions to find URL not containing certain info

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on a scraper/web crawler using Python 3.5 and the `re` module where one of its functions requires retrieving a YouTube channel's URL. I'm using the following portion of code that includes the matching of regular expression to accomplish this:

```
href = re.compile("(/user/|/channel/)(.+)")
```

What it should return is something like `/user/username` or `/channel/channelname`. It does this successfully for the most part, but every now and then it grabs a type of URL that includes more information like `/user/username/videos?view=60` or something else that goes on after the `username/` portion.

In an attempt to adress this issue, I rewrote the bit of code above as

```
href = re.compile("(/user/|/channel/)(?!(videos?view=60)(.+)")
```

along with other variations with no success. How can I rewrite my code so that it fetches URLS that do not include `videos?view=60` anywhere in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following approach with a specific regex pattern:

```
user_url = '/user/username/videos?view=60'
channel_url = '/channel/channelname/videos?view=60'

pattern = re.compile(r'(/user/|/channel/)([^/]+)')

m = re.match(pattern, user_url)
print(m.group())    # /user/username

m = re.match(pattern, channel_url)
print(m.group())    # /channel/channelname
```

Comment: @l'L'l, agreed, removed that

Answer (score 0):

I used This approach and it seems it does what you want.

```
import re

user = '/user/username/videos?view=60'
channel = '/channel/channelname/videos?view=60'

pattern = re.compile(r"(/user/|/channel/)[\w]+/")

user_match = re.search(pattern, user)

if user_match:
    print user_match.group()
else:
    print "Invalid Pattern"

pattern_match = re.search(pattern,channel)

if pattern_match:
    print pattern_match.group()
else:
    print "Invalid pattern"
```

Hope this helps!